# React testing library: The given element does not have a value setter when fireEvent change on input form

Tags: javascript, react-testing-library

I want to change the value of [material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) `TextField` in react testing library.
I already set up the data-testid. Then using `getByTestId` i picked up the input element.

```
// the component
<TextField
  data-testid="input-email"
  variant="outlined"
  margin="normal"
  required
  fullWidth
  id="email"
  label="Email Address"
  name="email"
  value={email}
  onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
  autoComplete="email"
  autoFocus
/>
// the test 
//...
let userInput = getByTestId('input-email')
fireEvent.change(userInput, { target: { value: 'correct@mail.com' } })
```

but this doesn't work as it's returning error: `The given element does not have a value setter`. Isn't the element uses `e.target.value` on it's `onChange` attribute? What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 90):

Problem here is [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api) is an abstraction in MaterialUI. It consists of FormControl, Label and Input. Clean way of solving this problem is:

- First, add `InputProps` on your TextField, with `data-testid` attribute.

```js
// YourComponent.js

<TextField
  onChange={event => setContent(event.target.value)}
  id="content"
  inputProps={{ "data-testid": "content-input" }}
  value={content}
  label="Content"
/>
```

- Then simply query using this ID.

```
// YourComponent.test.js

const contentInput = getByTestId("content-input");
fireEvent.change(contentInput, {
  target: { value: "new content" }
});

// and then assert stuff in here
```

Comment: coming back to this answer - it was right, but better way would be to `queryByLabelText` as mentioned in *Priority* section of queries: https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query#priority - but that requires different setup

Answer (score 31):

the issue here is when we use Material UI, it renders the **TextField component** having one of the elements inside it as an **input field**.
And **only "input" has getter and setter on it**. So after you got the TextField, you have **to get the "input" element of your TextField** using **querySelector()** of your DOM object.

```
const field = getByTestId('input-email').querySelector('input');
// now fire your event
fireEvent.change(field, { target: { value: 'abcd@xyz.com' } });
```

Comment: update - instead of using fireEvent, u can use userEvent from https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/ .
It is recommended to use this as it provides a more advanced simulation of browser interactions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `fireEvent.change` on an element that supports that event like `<input>`. In your case, I'm not sure what you're selecting. You can try to `debug(userInput)` to see what it returns.

Answer (score 5):

I tested the answers and comments and the only solutions that works for me was userEvent.

First install the dependency
`npm install --save-dev @testing-library/user-event`

Then in your test file calls:

```
import { render, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
    
    ...
it('Awesome input test', async () => {
await act(async () => {
    const inputMessage = getByTestId('input-send-message');
    userEvent.type(inputMessage, 'My awesome text...');
  })
})
//expect goes here
```

More [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/)

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had InputProps two times because I had an endAdornment. Just make sure that you put your data-testid attribute where it belongs. Example:

```js
<TextField
InputProps={
  {
    inputProps: {
      min: 0,
      'data-testid': 'value'
    },
    endAdornment: < InputAdornment position = "end" > % < /InputAdornment>,
  }
}
/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution here [Solution 2](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/react-testing-library-the-given-element-does-not-have-a-value-setter-when-fireevent-change-on-input-form)

using `screen.getByTestId('myId').querySelector('input')` I was able to change the value of my datepicker input