# I am facing problem to test my custom component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have created my custom component NumberInput field. I am new in writing test cases so I just try to write one simple test case and want to execute it successfully.

Here is my component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

import TextField from 'components/TextField';

function CustomInput(props) {
  return <TextField {...props} />;
}

function NumberInput(props) {
  const { onChange, ...otherProps } = props;
  return (
    <NumberFormat
      thousandSeparator
      decimalSeparator="."
      decimalScale={2}
      {...otherProps}
      customInput={CustomInput}
      onValueChange={values => {
        const { value } = values;
        onChange(value);
      }}
    />
  );
}

NumberInput.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
};

export default NumberInput;
```

and I am trying to write a test case for that

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { NumberInput } from '../index';


describe('<NumberInputField />', () => {
  it('Expect to have unit tests specified', () => {
    const { container } = render(<NumberInput />);

    const NumberFormat = container.firstChild
    fireEvent.change(NumberFormat, { target: { value: 10 } });
    expect(NumberFormat.value).toBe(10);
    //expect(true).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

I am trying to write a test case using

> Jest
>
> testing-library/react

this is My Error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `NumberInput` as a named export, but it is actually a default export.

Change `import { NumberInput } from '../index';` to `import NumberInput from '../index';`

OR

Change your export from `export default NumberInput;` to `export { NumberInput };`

Comment: Thank you Leon it's working for me. but now in line 

`fireEvent.change(NumberFormat, { target: { value: 10 } });`

showing error  The given element does not have a value setter

Comment: Could you help me with that?

Comment: It seems that's related to MaterialUI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110557/react-testing-library-the-given-element-does-not-have-a-value-setter-when-firee